# Typescript error "This expression is not callable ... has no call signatures.(2349)"

Tags: typescript

Please, help me fix this error:

```
type IValidator = (value?: string) => string | undefined;
type IComposeValidators = (validators: ((value?: string) => string | undefined)[]) => IValidator;

export const composeValidators: IComposeValidators = (...validators) => (value) => {
  return validators.reduce((error, validator) => error || validator(value), undefined); // This expression is not callable. Type '((value?: string | undefined) => string | undefined)[]' has no call signatures.(2349)
};
```

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgagQwDYEsAmDgHsBOUC8UAFAG7ICuEA-AFxQDOwOKAdgOYCUBAfA062ygAfKORZoIAM1YQ0AbgCwAKFCRYAYSwBbMFnoREqDNhz0CxMkcy56dIqQrU6jZuy75eLgcNHipMtA4AbQBdd154ZHRrHEUlZQgAD10cYCgAYywWRgztXX1DaJNbDTy9AyjjG3MiADp6yyKbcItHFoBvZSgoHAhgchwWKEaq01retHJ0iHsIHBxcABphypiWuYW8IRERmIckSg5lsQlpFlkOOIBfOSA)

Answer (score 0):

I finded solution:

```
type IValidator = (value?: string) => string | undefined;

export const composeValidators = (...validators: IValidator[]): IValidator => (value) => {
  return validators.reduce((error: string | undefined, validator) => error || validator(value), undefined);
};
```

Comment: FYI the reason it wasn't working before is because you were using `...validators` in the function, but the interface for `IComposeValidators` defines a single argument `validators` which is an array.  You would need to use `...validators` in the interface too.